# how to simplify if statement with 3 arguments

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

Need to simplify this function; all inputs are 0/1:

```
export const handleStepComplete = (userSave: number, concur: number, signature: number) => {
    if (userSave === 0 && concur === 0 && signature === 0) {
        return {completed: false, active: true, error: false};
    }
    if ((userSave === 1 && concur === 0 && signature === 0) ||
        (userSave === 1 && concur === 1 && signature === 0)) {
        return {completed: true, active: true, error: false};
    }
    if (userSave === 1 && concur === 0 && signature === 1) {
        return {completed: false, active: false, error: true};
    }
};
```

Comment: `userSave === 0 && concur === 0 && signature === 0` `userSave+concur+signature === 0` - the others ... probably not - though, `(userSave === 1 && concur === 0 && signature === 0) || (userSave === 1 && concur === 1 && signature === 0)` - just ignore concur ... so `(userSave === 1 && signature === 0)`

Comment: If they're all 0 and 1 then you can treat them as booleans: `if (!userSave && !concur && !signature)` and etc. Also, since all your cases are mutually exclusive perhaps it makes sense to use if/else

Comment: Not all cases are handled, is that by intent?

Comment: What are the possible inputs for the method? Can all of them be `1` or does that scenario never occur?

Comment: 0 or false is by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a draft, but you could structure it something like this.

```
export const handleStepComplete = (userSave: number, concur: number, signature: number) => {
    return {
        completed: (userSave && concur && signature),
        active: (userSave && !signature && !concur),
        error: (signature && !concur)
    }
};
```

This does not handle all cases, and neither does your code. The logic is probably not correct too, but you get the point and can build on it.

Comment: this is the most concice. I will implement it and let you know. Thanks

Comment: I made a few small changes, and it works like a charm. It also looks much better than all the If statements. Thanks!

Comment: export const handleStepComplete = (userSave: number, concur: number, signature: number) => {
    return {
        completed: (userSave && concur && signature),
        active: (userSave && !signature && !concur),
        error: (signature && !concur)
    }
};

Comment: @SergioRodriguez Great :) Updated the answer with your logic as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
export const handleStepComplete = (userSave: number, concur: number, signature: number) => {

    if (userSave === 0 && concur === 0 && signature === 0) {
        return {completed: false, active: true, error: false};
    }
    if(userSave === 1 && concur === 0 || 1 && signature === 0){
        return {completed: true, active: true, error: false};
    }
    if (userSave === 1 && concur === 0 && signature === 1) {
        return {completed: false, active: false, error: true};
    }
}
```

try this, I use or condition in the second if check, your two condition is
now in one condition

Comment: I like that. it is getting less messier.

Comment: If concur can really only be 0 or 1, you could even omit it at all in the second condition.

Answer (score 1):

This is the shortest I could come up with

```js
const handleStepComplete = (userSave, concur, signature) => {

    return {completed: Boolean(signature) ? false : Boolean(userSave), 
           active: Boolean(signature) ? false : !Boolean(concur), 
            error: Boolean(signature)};
 
};

const result = handleStepComplete(0,0,0);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you think of this ?
i have removed the types for params for it to work here in the comment section ... and added all possible cases that i can think of ..

```js
const handleStepComplete1 = (userSave, concur, signature) => {
 return {
 completed: (userSave === 1 && concur === 0 && signature === 0) ||
        (userSave === 1 && concur === 1 && signature === 0),
        active: (userSave === 0 && concur === 0 && signature === 0) ||  (userSave === 1 && concur === 0 && signature === 0) || (userSave === 1 && concur === 1 && signature === 0),
        error: (userSave === 1 && concur === 0 && signature === 1)
        };

};

 const handleStepComplete2 = (userSave, concur, signature) => ({
    completed: !!(userSave && !signature),
    active: !!(!(!userSave && concur) && !signature),
    error: !!(userSave && !concur && signature),
  });
  
 console.log(handleStepComplete1(0,0,0), handleStepComplete2(0,0,0))
console.log(handleStepComplete1(1,0,0), handleStepComplete2(1,0,0))
console.log(handleStepComplete1(0,1,0), handleStepComplete2(0,1,0))
console.log(handleStepComplete1(0,0,1), handleStepComplete2(0,0,1))
console.log(handleStepComplete1(0,1,1), handleStepComplete2(0,1,1))
console.log(handleStepComplete1(1,1,1), handleStepComplete2(1,1,1))
console.log(handleStepComplete1(1,1,0), handleStepComplete2(1,1,0))
console.log(handleStepComplete1(1,0,1), handleStepComplete2(1,0,1))
```